# Find most elegant way to return key if condition is set to true

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a python dictionary

```
slot_a = 'a'
slot_b = 'b'

# dict which lists all possible conditions
con_dict = {"branch_1": slot_a == 'a' and slot_b == 'b',
            "branch_2": slot_a == 'a' and slot_b == 'c'}
```

Now I want to return the key for the first true condition. In this case it's `branch_1`.

My solution is:

```
# Pick only the condition which is set to True
true_branch = [k for k, v in con_dict.items() if v == True]

true_branch
>>> branch_1
```

Since the number of branches can be very long, I was wondering, if there might be a more elegant way to get the same result?! Maybe `if / elif / else` and then return key? Or even something completely different? All I need at the end is the name of the true condition. Therefore working with a dict may not even be necessary.

Just asking for inspiration!

Comment: It's not particularly obvious without extra context if there's anything better to suggest. Could you not just do `for k, v in con_dict.items(): if v: return k`?

Comment: Well I guess my question is not so clear. Sorry for that. I think the best is to close this question. I need some time to think about it!

Comment: it is missing `[0]` to your `true_branch`: `true_branch = [...][0]`

Comment: comparison with `True` use `is`. Hint: `v` is already a boolean so just remove the redundant comparison with `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter). It will stop as soon it gets the first match without going through the whole "object".

```
ks, vs = zip(*con_dict.items()) # decoupling the list of pairs
i = 0
vs = iter(vs)     # terms are all booleans
while not next(vs):
    i += 1

del vs # "free" the iterator

print(ks[i])
```

or

```
true_branch = next((k for k, condition in con_dict.items() if condition), None)
print(true_branch)
```

Comment: Btw you could use `compress(con_dict, con_dict.values())` (from itertools), but really I think the question is broken... as they talk about at the end, they probably shouldn't use a dict in the first place.